# Excel JavaScript Add-in - Access to property denied

Tags: javascript, excel, add-in, excel-addins

I am currently working on a Excel JavaScript Add-In that is supposed to go through an extremely big amount of data to take a value from one column, separate it into certain strings and paste those strings into separate columns.

My problem is with accessing the value of the cell.
I am using the standard procedure (see below) which is also used in the sample code given by Visual Studio (Community 2017).
When I print all the possible properties of the given cell into the console, some have a note next to them that says: "<Erlaubnis verweigert.>" which is German for "<Access denied.>"
Therefore I can't access these properties and not get any result for the "value" property.

The strange thing is that the same code already worked in another project and therefore another project.

The code is basically:

```
var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("C1:C1").load("values,text");
var value = range.values[0][0];
```

The property notes:

[image]

I received the following error code:

> Error: PropertyNotLoaded: The property 'values' is not available. Before reading the property's value, call the load method on the containing object and call "context.sync()" on the associated request context.

I searched the internet a lot and tried to find an answer but I couldn't find anything. I hope you can help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59653709/68939 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/73646934/68939 ?

Answer (score -1):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59653573/office-scripts-error-the-property-is-not-available/59653709#59653709), your error message indicates that `context.sync()` is not being called. You need to include `context.sync()` to sync the data that JavaScript is loading with excel. Also `context.sync()` needs to be used in an asynchronous context to prevent your script from trying to use the data before it has finished being loaded and synced. Using [async/await or then/catch](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/11/comparison-async-await-versus-then-catch/) will correctly handle the sequence of events in your script and remove the error.

Comment: It appears this post was in whole or in part created with AI tools. Please note that [Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831) and read [Help Center: AI policy](/help/ai-policy).
It is not permitted to use AI tools to generate or reword content that you post on Stack Overflow, even if you vet this content beforehand. Work of others without [attribution](/help/referencing) also constitutes plagiarism. __Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.__

Comment: My answer was based off several duplicate questions, which I concatenated into my response here because it had a 250 rep bounty. I've adjusted my answer to more appropriately reflect that and cited the primary reference. This answer has not been generated using AI and does not contain misinformation, although at the time I initially posted this answer it may not have been 100% accurate because I had been awake for 2 days.