# Office Scripts error - the property is not available

Tags: excel, office-scripts

I've created a script with the new [Office Scripts in Excel on the web](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/announcing-office-scripts-preview/ba-p/1093559). The script simply sets the fill color for a range in the current worksheet, gets the used range, and then tries to write the range's address to the console.

```
async function main(context: Excel.RequestContext) {
  let workbook = context.workbook;
  let worksheets = workbook.worksheets;
  let selectedSheet = worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
  selectedSheet.getRange("B3:E6").format.fill.color = "E2EFDA";

  // write used range to console
  let usedRange = selectedSheet.getUsedRange();
  usedRange.load("address");
  context.sync();
  console.log("used range = " + usedRange.address);
}
```

Running this script generates the following error message:

`The property 'address' is not available. Before reading the property's value, call the load method on the containing object and call "context.sync()" on the associated request context.`

Seems like I'm already doing as the error message guidance suggests -- i.e., calling the `load` method to load the `address` property and then calling `context.sync()` after the load. What am I missing here?

Comment: It should be noted that this asynchronous code is no longer in Office Scripts. Office Scripts no longer need the `load`/`sync` pattern.

Comment: [^^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59653573/office-scripts-error-the-property-is-not-available/59653709#comment131120825_59653573) See for details: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/announcing-a-simplified-api-for-office-scripts/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note:** This answer is for the preview version of Office Scripts that still required `context.sync()`. Before the general availability release, [the API was changed](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/announcing-a-simplified-api-for-office-scripts/) so you didn't have to do `context.sync()` calls. So this answer (and question) only apply to the preview version of Office Scripts.

---

You'll need to add `await` before `context.sync();` (so it becomes `await context.sync();`).

`context.sync()` is an asynchronous action, meaning the script will continue running before the `sync` finishes. Since the next line of your script requires information from the workbook, that `sync` needs to be completed before continuing. Changing the line to `await context.sync();` ensures the synchronization between the workbook and your script is done and successful before proceeding.

There's more about this in the article [Scripting fundamentals for Office Scripts in Excel on the web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/develop/scripting-fundamentals#context).

Comment: I am not using any async action, in my case I'm simply calling `table.getColumnByName(colHeader).getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal()` and I get this error. Interestingly it was working before. Any idea?

Comment: I just found out that the error comes up whenever I call that get range function within a for-each `map.forEach((v,k)=> {})`. Any idea?

Comment: @xbmono - Are you using Office Scripts or a JavaScript API add-on? If you're using the latter, the way the Excel JavaScript API works, you make calls like that to tell Excel what you want it to do and then you call `context.sync()` to have Excel actually do it. `sync` returns a promise, so you have to either use an `async` function and `await` that promise, or use the promise methods `.then` and `.catch`. But you don't need that for Office Scripts, they changed the API between the preview (which this question addresses) and the general release. I've added a note at the beginning of the answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am using Office Script and that's why I am confused, it shouldn't need any of those things you mentioned, yet it won't work. The only solution I found is using `for loop` and `map.keys.next()` function, but `forEach` seems to run in a multi-threaded way, I'm saying this because with that I can see the logs order goes irrational.

Comment: @xbmono - Yeah, I haven't used Office Scripts. I don't know if they have some non-standard behavior. Sorry. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder no worries... all good