# Before reading the property's value, call the load method on the containing object and call "context.sync()" on the associated request context

Tags: javascript, powerpoint, office-addins

I am working on an angular add-in for PowerPoint.
And trying to print the slide.id property value in the console but it gives me an error. Here is the code. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

```
PowerPoint.run(function (context) {
  var collection = context.presentation.getSelectedSlides().load("items");
  context.sync();
  var slide0 = collection.getItemAt(0);
  context.sync();

  slide0.load("id");
  context.sync();

  console.log(slide0.id); /* this gives error: RichApi.Error: The property 'id' is not available. Before reading the property's value, call the load method on the containing object and call "context.sync()" on the associated request context. */

  console.log(slide0); /* Gives gives the right output along with id value*/
  return context.sync(slide0);
});
```

Also, how do I use the id outside the .run block?

I am using the preview API : https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js

Answer (score 3):

You must call `load(key)` to load the property before reading it.

And `sync()` returns a promise, you must wait for it.

So the answer is:

```js
async function getFirstSlideId() {
    return await PowerPoint.run(async function (context) {
      context.presentation.load('slides');
      await context.sync();
      // get the first slide id. example: 256#3810858458
      return context.presentation.slides.items[0].id;
    });
}
```